# Multiple shortcuts for QAbstractButton

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to add multiple shortcuts for QAbstractButton with Qt Creator or by modifying .ui file? In Qt Creator I am only able to add one shortcut. Duplicating the property elements in the .ui file results in only the last shortcut to be active. Adding another string element within the property doesn't seem to do anything. I've came across solutions by code modification, however my goal is to generate the UI via the .ui file without any code.

.ui file:

```
 <property name="shortcut">
    <string>S, 8</string>
</property>
```

[qtcreator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwIhx.png)

Comment: No, it's not possible in the ui file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with QAction

```
QAction *buttonAction = new QAction(ui->pushButton);
buttonAction->setShortcuts({QKeySequence("Ctrl+S"),QKeySequence("Ctrl+P")});
ui->pushButton->addAction(buttonAction);

connect(buttonAction, &QAction::triggered, ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::click);

connect(ui->pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [](){
    qDebug()<<"click";
});
```